# std::bind, can't get method with single parameter to work

Tags: c++, bind

The following code works:

```
struct Foo {
    void print(int n1, int n2)
    {
        std::cout << n1 << " " << n2 << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo foo;
auto f = std::bind(&Foo::print, &foo, 95, _1);
f(5);
```

But if I want to bind to a method with a single parameter:

```
struct Foo {
    void print(int n1)
    {
        std::cout << n1 << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo foo;
auto f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print, &foo, 95, _1);
f3();
```

I get a long list of errors:

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -fno-rtti -pedantic -Wextra -pthread -std=c++17 -g   -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/8/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_check_arity<void (Foo::*)(int), Foo*, int, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>':
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:787:12:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(int), Foo*, int, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>'
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:808:5:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (Foo::*)(int); _BoundArgs = {Foo*, int, const std::_Placeholder<1>&}]'
main.cpp:152:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:775:7: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member
       static_assert(_Varargs::value
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       ? sizeof...(_BoundArgs) >= _Arity::value + 1
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       : sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == _Arity::value + 1,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:153:8: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, int, std::_Placeholder<1>))(int)>) ()'
     f3();
        ^
In file included from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:480:2: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (Foo::*)(int); _Bound_args = {Foo*, int, std::_Placeholder<1>}]'
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:480:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:491:2: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (Foo::*)(int); _Bound_args = {Foo*, int, std::_Placeholder<1>}]'
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:491:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:509:2: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (Foo::*)(int); _Bound_args = {Foo*, int, std::_Placeholder<1>}]'
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:509:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/functional:521:2: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (Foo::*)(int); _Bound_args = {Foo*, int, std::_Placeholder<1>}]'
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
```

Comment: If you want to bind to a method with only one parameter, why are you passing two parameters (`95` and `_1`)?

Comment: I simply had the wrong idea of "placeholders" in mind. I thought wrongly that _1 means it replaces parameter _1. But _1 means the first parameter is passed to the callable parameter list. Go this now ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_1`, `_2`, etc. are representation of argument of resulting callable object. E.g.

```
struct Foo {
    void print(int n1)
    {
        std::cout << n1 << " " << n2 << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo foo;
auto f = std::bind(&Foo::print, &foo, _2, _1);
f(5,4); //would call foo.print(4,5)
```

So if you need to bind  `void (Foo::*)(int)` to  callable with signature `void (*)(int)`, you have to write

```
auto f = std::bind(&Foo::print, &foo, _1);
```

Note that in C++11 (and some C++03 compilers, e.g. Microsoft VS2010+) and later you can use lambda expressions to do the same.

Comment: I only want to show my colleagues the old things before lambda ass a demonstration. I never used bind for years now cause of lambda :-)

Comment: @Klaus There was some scary example of bind use in answer here... and lambda alternative: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643892/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-c/645706#645706 ...

Answer (score 2):

You have wrongly copy-pasted code. Try this:

```
struct Foo {
    void print(int n1)
    {
        std::cout << n1 << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo foo;
auto f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print, &foo, 95);
f3();
```